# Finding a distance between two line segments?

Tags: algorithm, math, 3d

Given two line segments, find the two points at which the distance between the line segments is *d*.

This is similar to the "shortest distance between two line segments problem", except we are solving for the two points on the line segment separated by a given distance *d*.

Each line segment consists of two 3-dimensional points.

The math that I have found through google searches both scare and confuse me. I am a programmer, but I struggle to understand the proofs and analytics behind solving a problem like this.

**Input:** 2 line segments and a distance *d*

**Output:** 2 points on each segment that are a distance *d* from each other, or *None* if no two points exist

Comment: It will usually be the case that infinitely many pairs of points will have the distance d. Which pair should be returned? Any?

Comment: What is the definition of "distance between two lines" in this case? The standard definition usually imply that the smallest vector joining the lines is perpendicular to both lines. Such a vector is unique (unless lines are parallel) and so the smallest distance. So if you need the two points at a distance "d" that is not the closest one, you have to constrain more the distance definition since there are multiple points meeting that condition. For instance you can ask for distance "d" for which the vector joining the points is normal to one line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a non-iterative solution. I fear that the maths may irritate you, though there is nothing complicated here.

First off it is easiest to work with distances squared throughout.

It one threeD line is described by points P and Q, and the other by points R and S, then one way of stating the problem is that we want to find scalars m and n so that the distance squared between a point a fraction m along the first line, and a point a fraction n along the second is the given dsq.

We must restrict m and n to be between 0 and 1 (inclusive), so that our points are really on the line segments.

If have m and n, then the points are

```
X = P + m*(Q-P)
Y = R + n*(S-R)
```

Suppose we were first to find the minimum and maximum values of Dsq. This would tell us whether there was a solution: if the given value of dsq is either less than the minimum or greater than the maximum, there is no solution, and we can stop.

Let the m and n values for the points at which the minimum occurs be m_min and n_min, and those for the maximum be m_max and n_max. If we introduce a new variable z (in [0,1]) then we can consider a 'line' of m,n, values:

```
m(z) = m_min + z*(m_max-m_min)
n(z) = n_min + z*(n_max-n_min)
```

when z is 0, these are the values for the minimum Dsq, while for z=1, they are for the maximim Dsq. So as we increase z from 0 to 1, the value of Dsq must pass through the value we want! That is, we just need to search for the value of z that makes Dsq be the value we want.

What makes the problem (relatively) straightforward is that the distanceSquared between X and Y is a second order polynomial in m and n. Specifically, some tedious algebra shows that, if Dsq is the distance squared between X and Y,

```
Dsq = a + 2*b*m + 2*c*m + d*m*m + 2*e*m*n + f*m*m
where, in terms of dot products
a = (P-R).(P-R)
b = (P-R).(Q-P)
c =-(P-R).(S-R)
d = (Q-P).(Q-P)
e =-(Q-P).(S-R)
f = (S-R).(S-R)
```

The maximum and minimum must occur at either one of the corners ( (m,n)=(0,0) or (0,1) or (1,0) or (1,1)) or along one of the edges ( at (0,n) or (1,n) for some n, or (m,0) or (m,1) for some m) or at a point in the middle where the derivatives of Dsq (with respect to m and n) are both 0).
Note for example that on the edge say (0,n) we get a quadratic in n for Dsq, so it's easy to find the maximum of that.

Further more, when we come to look along the 'line' between the minimum and maximum values, if we substitute m(z) and n(z) into our formula for Dsq, we get, after more tedious algebra, a quadratic in z, and so it's easy to find the value of z that will give the desired value of Dsq.

Well, this post is already rather long, so here's C code that implements these ideas. I tried a million random values for the points, when the distance was always between the max and the min, it always found appropriate 3d points. On my (fairly ordinary) linux desktop this took a few seconds.

```
   //   3d vectors
static  void    v3_sub( double* P, double* Q, double* D)
{   D[0] = P[0]-Q[0];
    D[1] = P[1]-Q[1];
    D[2] = P[2]-Q[2];
}
static  double  v3_dot( double* P, double* Q)
{   return P[0]*Q[0] + P[1]*Q[1] + P[2]*Q[2];
}

//  quadratic in one variable
// return *x so X -> r[0] + 2*r[1]*X + r[2]*X*X has minumum at *x
static  int quad_min( const double*r, double* x)
{   if ( r[2] <= 0.0)
    {   return 0;
    }
    *x = -r[1]/r[2];
    return 1;
}

// return x so r[0] + 2*r[1]*x + r[2]*x*x == d, and whether 0<=x<=1
static  int solve_quad( const double* r, double d, double* x)
{
double  ap = r[0] - d;
    if ( r[1] > 0.0)
    {
    double  root1 = -(r[1] + sqrt( r[1]*r[1] - ap*r[2]));   // < 0 
        *x = ap/root1;
    }
    else
    {
    double  root1 = (-r[1] + sqrt( r[1]*r[1] - ap*r[2]));   // >= 0
        if ( root1 < r[2])
        {   *x = root1/r[2];
        }
        else
        {   *x = ap/root1;
        }
    }
    return 0.0 <= *x && *x <= 1.0;
}

//  quadratic in 2 variables
typedef struct
{   double  a,b,c,d,e,f;
}   quad2T;

static  double  eval_quad2( const quad2T* q, double m, double n)
{
    return  q->a
    +   2.0*(m*q->b + n*q->c)
    +   m*m*q->d + 2.0*m*n*q->e + n*n*q->f
    ;
}

// eval coeffs of quad2 so that quad2(m,n) = distsq( P+m*(Q-P), R+n*(S-R))
static  quad2T  set_quad2( double* P, double* Q, double* R, double* S)
{
double  D[3];   v3_sub( P, R, D);
double  U[3];   v3_sub( Q, P, U);
double  V[3];   v3_sub( S, R, V);
quad2T  q;
    // expansion of lengthSq( D+m*U-n*V)
    q.a = v3_dot( D, D);
    q.b = v3_dot( D, U);
    q.c = -v3_dot( D, V);
    q.d = v3_dot( U, U);
    q.e = -v3_dot( U, V);
    q.f = v3_dot( V, V);
    return q;
}

// if gradient of q is 0 in [0,1]x[0,1], return (m,n) where it is zero
// gradient of q is 2*( q->b + m*q->d + n*q->e, q->c + m*q->e + n*q->f)
// so must solve    ( q->d  q->e ) * (m) = -(q->b)
//          ( q->e  q->f )   (n)    (q->c)
static  int dq_zero( const quad2T* q, double* m, double* n)
{
double  det = q->d*q->f - q->e*q->e;
    if ( det <= 0.0)
    {   // note matrix be semi-positive definite, so negative determinant is rounding error
        return 0;
    }
    *m  = -( q->f*q->b - q->e*q->c)/det;
    *n  = -(-q->e*q->b + q->d*q->c)/det;

    return  0.0 <= *m && *m <= 1.0
    &&  0.0 <= *n && *n <= 1.0
    ;
}

// fill *n with minimising value, if any in [0,1], of n -> q(m0,n)
static  int m_edge_min( const quad2T* q, double m0, double* n)
{
double  r[3];   // coeffs of poly in n when m == m0
    r[0] = q->a + 2.0*m0*q->b + m0*m0*q->d;
    r[1] = q->c + m0*q->e;
    r[2] = q->f;
    return  ( quad_min( r, n)
        && *n > 0.0 && *n < 1.0
        );
}

// fill *m with minimising value, if any in [0,1], of m -> q(m,n0)
static  int n_edge_min( const quad2T* q, double* m, double n0)
{
double  r[3];   // coeffs of poly in m when n == n0
    r[0] = q->a + 2.0*n0*q->c + n0*n0*q->f;
    r[1] = q->b + n0*q->e;
    r[2] = q->d;
    return  ( quad_min( r, m)
        && *m > 0.0 && *m < 1.0
        );
}

// candidates for min, man
typedef struct
{   double  m,n;    // steps along lines
    double  d;  // distance squared between points
}   candT;

static  int find_cands( const quad2T* q, candT* c)
{
int nc = 0;
double  x, y;
    // the corners
    c[nc++] = (candT){ 0.0,0.0, eval_quad2( q, 0.0, 0.0)};
    c[nc++] = (candT){ 0.0,1.0, eval_quad2( q, 0.0, 1.0)};
    c[nc++] = (candT){ 1.0,1.0, eval_quad2( q, 1.0, 1.0)};
    c[nc++] = (candT){ 1.0,0.0, eval_quad2( q, 1.0, 0.0)};
    // the edges
    if ( m_edge_min( q, 0.0, &x))
    {   c[nc++] = (candT){ 0.0,x, eval_quad2( q, 0.0, x)};
    }
    if ( m_edge_min( q, 1.0, &x))
    {   c[nc++] = (candT){ 1.0,x, eval_quad2( q, 1.0, x)};
    }
    if ( n_edge_min( q, &x, 0.0))
    {   c[nc++] = (candT){ x, 0.0, eval_quad2( q, x, 0.0)};
    }
    if ( n_edge_min( q, &x, 1.0))
    {   c[nc++] = (candT){ x, 1.0, eval_quad2( q, x, 1.0)};
    }
    // where the derivatives are 0
    if ( dq_zero( q, &x, &y))
    {   c[nc++] = (candT){ x, y, eval_quad2( q, x, y)};
    }
    return nc;
}

// fill in r so that
// r[0] + 2*r[1]*z + r[2]*z*z = q( minm+z*(maxm-minm), minn+x*(maxn-minn))
static  void    form_quad
( const quad2T* q
, double minm, double maxm
, double minn, double maxn
, double* r
)
{
double  a = minm;
double  c = maxm-minm;
double  b = minn;
double  d = maxn-minn;
    r[0] =  q->a + 2.0*q->b*a + 2.0*q->c*b + q->d*a*a + 2.0*q->e*a*b + q->f*b*b;
    r[1] =  q->b*c + q->c*d + q->d*a*c + q->e*(a*d+b*c) + q->f*b*d;
    r[2] =  q->d*c*c + 2.0*q->e*c*d + q->f*d*d;
}

static  int find_points
( double* P, double* Q, double* R, double* S, double dsq, double* X, double* Y
)
{
double  m, n;
quad2T  q = set_quad2( P, Q, R, S);
candT   c[9];
int nc = find_cands( &q, c);    // find candidates for max and min
    // find indices of max and min
int imin = 0;
int imax = 0;
    for( int i=1; i<nc; ++i)
    {   if ( c[i].d < c[imin].d)
        {   imin = i;
        }
        else if ( c[i].d > c[imax].d)
        {   imax = i;
        }
    }
    // check if solution is possible -- should allow some slack here!
    if ( c[imax].d < dsq || c[imin].d > dsq)
    {   return 0;
    }
    // find solution 
double  r[3];
    form_quad( &q, c[imin].m, c[imax].m, c[imin].n, c[imax].n, r);
double  z;
    if ( solve_quad( r, dsq, &z))
    {   // fill in distances along
        m = c[imin].m + z*(c[imax].m - c[imin].m);
        n = c[imin].n + z*(c[imax].n - c[imin].n);
        // compute points
        for( int i=0; i<3; ++i)
        {   X[i] = P[i] + m*(Q[i]-P[i]);
            Y[i] = R[i] + n*(S[i]-R[i]);
        }
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved using elementary algebra just solving a quadratic polynomial. Look at the following derivation:

Given line segment P defined by points P1 and P2 and line segment Q defined by points Q1 and Q2 we can define the ray P(t) as:

P(t) = P1 + t V

Where t is a positive scalar and V is the unit vector:

V = (P2 - P1) / |P2 - P1|

And the line segment Q(t) as:

Q(t) = Q1 + t (Q2 - Q1)

Where t is a positive scalar in the interval [0 1].

The shortest distance of any point in line Q(t) to the line P is given by the projection of the point on the line P. The projection is along the normal vector of the line P.

```
             Q(t)
               |
               |
P1 ------------x------------ P2
```

So we are looking for a point x in line P such that the length of the vector (x - Q(t)) is equal to d:

|x - Q(t)|^2 = d^2

The point x can be computed using the ray P(t) 
since t = (Q(t) - P1) • V:

x = P((Q(t) - P1) • V)

x = P1 + ((Q(t) - P1) • V) V

x = P1 -  (P1 • V) V + (Q(t)  • V) V

x = P1 -  (P1 • V) V + (Q1• V) V + t ((Q2 - Q1) • V ) V

Where (•) is the dot product.

x = C +  t D

Where

C = P1 -  (P1 • V) V + (Q1• V) V

D = ((Q2 - Q1) • V ) V

Now the equation looks like this:

|C + t D - Q1 - t (Q2 - Q1)|^2 = d^2

|C - Q1 + t (D  - Q2 + Q1)|^2 = d^2

Grouping terms:

|t A + B|^2 = d^2

Where

A = (D  - Q2 + Q1)

B = C - Q1

Taking the square we have:

(t A + B) • (t A + B) = d^2

t^2 (A • A) + 2 t (A • B) + (B • B - d^2) = 0

Which is a simple quadratic polynomial. Solving for t we can get two values, if both are complex numbers then there are no real answer. If both are real then we have two answers probably due to symmetry we have to choose one t in the interval [0 1].

Once we have t we can compute the point in line segment Q using Q(t) and a corresponding point x in line P

x = P((Q(t) - P1) • V)

If the parameter (Q(t) - P1) • V is in the interval [0 L], where L is the length of vector (P2 - P1), then x lies within the ends of segment line P, otherwise x is outside and then no answer has found.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the 2 endpoints of line A are different distances from the closest endpoint on line B I would use a brute force method. I would choose the centerpoint of line A as one end of line C and slide the other end of line C on line B in steps of "insert distance" until I was within "insert distance" of distance "d".

If the closest I came to "d" was too large I would set the new endpoint of line C on A to be halfway b/t the centerpoint of A and the closest endpoint of line A to the closest endpoint on line B. If the closest I came to "d" was too small I would move the new endpoint on A halfway b/t the centerpoint of A and the farthest endpoint of line A to the closest endpoint on line B.

Repeat this process for "insert steps" iterations and return the endpoints that gave me the closest distance to "d" if an acceptable value was not found before the maximum number of iterations was reached. Then you could determine if your algorithm is not allowing for enough steps or has an overly-stringent value for being close to "d".

If the 2 endpoints of line A are the same distance from the closest endpoint on line B, then use the farthest endpoint of line B. If these are both identical, it is arbitrary in which direction the initial step occurs.

Also, instead of simply sliding the 2nd endpoint on line B you could use the same algorithm of jumping to smaller and smaller midpoints (in the correct direction) to save on the number of computations.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s an iterative algorithm that requires some math but not a sophisticated understanding of mathematical optimization. It’s robust but perhaps not especially fast.

At a high level, this algorithm is like binary search (technically, ternary search). In each pair of iterations, we chop off a constant fraction of what remains of each segment, taking care to preserve a valid solution if one exists. We can prove mathematically that, in the limit as the number of iterations increases, both segments shrink to points, and these points are a valid solution if one exists. In practice, we stop after some number of iterations (e.g., one hundred, or when the segments are short enough) and return an arbitrary point on each segment.

This algorithm uses two mathematical ingredients. The first is a formula that computes the distance between a point and a line segment. The second is the fact that, as we sweep a point along one segment, the distance to the other decreases and then increases.

I’ll expand this description if I have time.

```
from __future__ import division


def squared_distance_between_points(p, q):
    """Returns the squared distance between the point p and the point q."""
    px, py, pz = p
    qx, qy, qz = q
    return (px - qx)**2 + (py - qy)**2 + (pz - qz)**2


def squared_distance_between_point_and_segment(p, q, r):
    """Returns the squared distance between the point p and the segment qr."""
    px, py, pz = p
    qx, qy, qz = q
    rx, ry, rz = r
    # Translate the points to move q to the origin (p' = p - q and r' = r - q).
    px -= qx
    py -= qy
    pz -= qz
    rx -= qx
    ry -= qy
    rz -= qz
    # Project p' onto the line 0r'.
    # The point on this line closest to p' is cr'.
    c = (px * rx + py * ry + pz * rz) / (rx * rx + ry * ry + rz * rz)
    # Derive c' by clamping c. The point on the segment 0r' closest to p is c'r'.
    c = min(max(c, 0), 1)
    # Compute the distance between p' and c'r'.
    return squared_distance_between_points((px, py, pz),
                                           (c * rx, c * ry, c * rz))


def trisect(p, q):
    """Returns the point one-third of the way from the point p to the point q."""
    px, py, pz = p
    qx, qy, qz = q
    return ((2 * px + qx) / 3, (2 * py + qy) / 3, (2 * pz + qz) / 3)


def find_points_on_segments_at_distance(p, r, s, u, d, iterations=100):
    """Returns a point q on the segment pr and a point t on the segment su
       such that the distance between q and t is approximately d.
       If this is not possible (or barely possible), returns None."""
    d **= 2
    feasible = False
    for i in range(2 * int(iterations)):
        q1 = trisect(p, r)
        d1 = squared_distance_between_point_and_segment(q1, s, u)
        q2 = trisect(r, p)
        d2 = squared_distance_between_point_and_segment(q2, s, u)
        if d <= min(d1, d2):
            # Use convexity to cut off one third of the search space.
            if d1 <= d2:
                r = q2
            else:
                p = q1
        elif d <= max(d1, d2):
            # There is certainly a solution in the middle third.
            feasible = True
            p = q1
            r = q2
        elif (d <= squared_distance_between_points(p, s)
              or d <= squared_distance_between_points(p, u)):
            # There is certainly a solution in the first third.
            feasible = True
            r = q1
        elif (d <= squared_distance_between_points(r, s)
              or d <= squared_distance_between_points(r, u)):
            # There is certainly a solution in the last third.
            feasible = True
            p = q2
        else:
            # Definitely infeasible.
            return None
        # Swap the segments.
        p, r, s, u = s, u, p, r
    if not feasible:
        return None
    return p, r
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is the topic of the article [On fast computation of distance between line segments](https://jasoncantarella.com/octrope/trunk/doc/lumelsky.pdf) by Vladimir J. LUMELSKY 1985.

The general algorithm is as follows:

1. Compute the global MinD (minimum Euclidean distance, global means the distance between two infinite lines containing the segments) and coordinates of both points (bases) of the line of minimum distances, see [skew lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_lines#Nearest_points); if both bases lie inside the segments, then actual MinD is equal to the global MinD; otherwise, continue.
2. Compute distances between the endpoints of both segments (a total of four distances).
3. Compute coordinates of the base points of perpendiculars from the endpoints of one segment onto the other segment; compute the lengths of those perpendiculars whose base points lie inside the corresponding segments (up to four base point, and four distances).
4. Out of the remaining distances, the smallest is the sought actual MinD.
   Altogether, this represents the computation of six points and of nine distances.

The article further describes and proves how to reduce the amount of tests based on the data received in initial steps of the algorithm and how to handle degenerate cases (e.g. equal endpoints of a segment).

C-language implementation by Eric Larsen can be found [here](https://github.com/MeshInspector/MeshLib/blob/master/source/MRMesh/MRTriDist.cpp), see `SegPoints()` function.